# Make generic method that takes 2 different generic types in c# is it

Tags: c#, generics, methods, arguments

I'm trying to make method that reads 3 different lists, but they should be generic.
We know that a generic list can be read like:

```
public void msgList<T>(List<T> readlist)
{
//do something with generic readlist, as long as T is Int, double or something else
}
```

But suppose you want to read 2 arguments in that method, and that one is a list of integers, and another is a list of doubles for example

```
public void msgList<T>(List<T> readlist, List<T> readsecondlist)
{
//do something with generic readlist and readsecondlist
}
```

I intend in the above that the readlist is of integers, and readsecondlist is a list of doubles, or any other generic type. Is something like this possible?

Kind regards,

Comment: try msgList<T1,T2>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple [generic type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters) :

```
public void msgList<TFirst, TSecond>(List<TFirst> readlist, List<TSecond> readsecondlist)
{
    //do something with generic readlist and readsecondlist
}
```